# Passing paramters to system() function in PHP

Tags: php, linux

I want to passing the parameters on following function:

system("/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/foldername/filename.php > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &");

I have tried following things but no luck.

1. system("/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/foldername/filename.php?abc=123 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &");
2. system("/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/foldername/filename.php abc=123> /dev/null 2> /dev/null &");

Please explain me how i pass the parameter and how i get this parameter value on this example.php file.

Thanks

Comment: command line php does accept get strings. It is a file, not a url. You can pass arguments to the file as you would any command line script (space separated single words or quoted strings) and access those via `$argv`. You can read more about php's command line usage in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php and http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan Kuhn, you mean 
system("/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/foldername/filename.php 123 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &"); right ?

Comment: You're executing on the command line. The shell has NO idea what a URL is. It's going to see the `?` as a wildcard attempt, and spit out a "no match" error.

Comment: Yes, and 123 will be available at `$argv[1]` in  your script (might be another index, should check with `print_r($argv)`). Really, you could pass a query string formatted string (I would suggest quoting it) and use parse_str to get the keys/values. `$_GET = parse_str($argv[1]);`.

Comment: Thank you @Marc B, so what should i do ?

Comment: exactly as you suggested. treat the query value as if it was a command-line argument. `...filename.php abc=123`, which you can then retrieve from `$argv[1]`, and split into key/value pairs.

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan Kuhn, it's working super!

Comment: I pretty much repeated my comments below in an answer so the question can be answered/closed. Oh, and I made a mistake in my first comment. "command line php **doesn't**..." is what I meant to say.

Comment: Thank you again 'Marc B' and 'Jonathan Kuhn.'

Answer (score 2):

Command line php doesn't accept get strings. It is a file, not a url. You can pass arguments to the file as you would any command line script (space separated single words or quoted strings) and access those via `$argv`. You can read more about php's command line usage in the manual:

php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php
php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

You could also pass a query string formatted string (I would suggest quoting it) and use [parse_str](http://www.php.net/parse_str) to get the keys/values.

Cmd line: `php scriptName.php "foo=1&bar=2"`

in script:

```
$queryString = parse_str($argv[1]);
//and now you have:
$queryString['foo']; //equals 1
$queryString['bar']; //equals 2
```